Kubuntu - Monitors connected through USB-C dock only work on TTY, not on desktop
I have an Intel NUC (NUC12WSKi5) running Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, that functions as a kind of server and as a workstation. So it's always running, but sometimes I want to plug in the USB-C hub (HP Dock G4) on my desk and work on it directly.
But every time I find myself with the following problem: when I plug in the USB-C dock, the two monitors behind the dock say nothing is connected. Then I switch to TTY3 ([CTRL] + [F3]) and behold, the monitors switch on and I see the login prompt, duplicated on both screens. Then I switch back to the desktop ([CTRL] + [F2]) and the screens seem to disconnect again.
[CTRL] + [F1] just shows a blank screen with the blinking underscore in the corner.
The GPU is an integrated Intel Iris Xe Graphics G7. The monitors are connected with DisplayPort.
EDIT: I just noticed that disconnecting the dock and connecting the monitor directly with HDMI actually has identical results, so I guess it isn't just the dock.
I can get my monitors working by rebooting after the dock is connected. Though the screens won't recognize any output during the disk decryption key, I have to enter that blindly.
Any advice? Why would the monitors not work on the desktop environment but do work on the TTY?
